# Local storage and persistent state in React

Tags: reactjs

I want to make a like button where user can click and like something. When user clicks the button remains red even after refresh. How can i implement this?

I have this code. When i refresh the local storage gets reset. How can i get around this?

```
useEffect(() => {
  setColor(window.localStorage.getItem('color'));
}, []);

    useEffect(() => {
     window.localStorage.setItem('color', color);
}, [color]);

    
const handleClick =  () => {
  setClicked(prevValue => !prevValue)

  if(clicked){
    setColor("red")
  }else{
    setColor("")
 }
}

    <div className="App">
      <div className="container">
       <button style={{backgroundColor: color}} onClick={handleClick} > +</button>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: can you try to add if check while setting the item to the storage? ` if(color)` like this

Comment: Testing it out in codesandbox, it works fine

Comment: The problem was in my browser i think. I got it to stop refreshing but i still have to click twice to make it red. I think it has something to do with the state being used right after setting it. "if(clicked)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach. We need check twice `localStorage` first when the component mounting, second when we clicked the button. [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-shape-jmwh1?file=/src/App.js:295-306)

**App.js**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
const App = () => {
  const [color, setColor] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const lS = window.localStorage.getItem("color");
    if (lS) return setColor(lS);
    localStorage.setItem("color", "");
  }, []);

  const handleClick = () => {
    const lS = window.localStorage.getItem("color");
    if (lS === "") {
      localStorage.setItem("color", "red");
      setColor("red");
    }
    if (lS !== "") {
      localStorage.setItem("color", "");
      setColor("");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="container">
        <button
          style={{ backgroundColor: color }}
          className="like-button"
          onClick={handleClick}
        >
          +
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to duplicate this error in a sandbox. However, on my machine it works. Could it be that you have localStorage.removeItem('color') somewhere else in your project and gets called? Or maybe a problem with your browser. Here is the sandbox where it works: https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-shannon-cot7i?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I've also tried on sandbox and it works. But his handleClick function has a flaw maybe it's related to that.

Comment: Yes it is working in your example, but when you initially click the button you must click it twice. Why is that? You can check by refreshing also

Answer (score 0):

I hope, it will work I have not tested it but I am sure it should work

```js
useEffect(() => {

const storedColor = localStorage.getItem('color')

  if(storedColor) {
   setColor(storedColor);
  }
}, []);
    
const handleClick =  () => {
  setClicked(prevValue => !prevValue)

  if(clicked){
    setColor("red");
    localStorage.setItem('color', color);
  }else{
    setColor("")
 }
}

  return <div className="App">
      <div className="container">
       <button style={{backgroundColor: color}} onClick={handleClick} > +           </button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: No, sorry it did not work. Local storage gets overwritten i think. The main issue is that you have to click twice to be able to change the color.

Comment: Can you share the link to sandbox?

Comment: When you refresh, you can see it goes back to its initial state. It is not maintaining the color red.

Comment: check the link now it started working.
But I don't know it is best practice or not.

Comment: Still the issue of clicking it two times to make it work. You can check on initial rendering. You have to click twice.